# react async hook how to do it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is my react component..

```js
const DashboardContext = React.createContext()

function DashboardStateProvider({ children }) {
  const wallet = useWallet()

  const Provider = DashboardContext.Provider

  if (wallet.account)
    return (
      <WithSubscription Provider={Provider} connectedAccount={wallet.account}>
        {children}
      </WithSubscription>
    )

  return (
    <Provider
      value={{
        
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

async function WithSubscription({ Provider, connectedAccount, children }) {
  // Juror ANT balances, 24h ANT movements and claimed subscription fees
  const data = await apiCALL(connectedAccount)

  // bla bla bla code here
}

function useDashboardState() {
  return useContext(DashboardContext)
}

export { DashboardStateProvider, useDashboardState }
```

The problem is that it shows an error when I use `async` on the `withSubscription` function. It's really mandatory, because in it, I am making an async call `await apiCALL`.

ERROR:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

Any ideas ? I have to fix this and i am not a react developer, so I'd appreciate the direct answer what to change exactly.

UPDATE:

How do I use `useDashboardState` ?

```js
import { useDashboardState } from '../components/Dashboard/DashboardStateProvider'

 const {
    data
  } = useDashboardState()
```

Comment: Problem is in the `useDashboardState` function; specifically because of the call to `useContext` inside this function. Hooks can only be called at the top-level of a React component.

Comment: why does it work without `async`  on the `WithSubscription` ?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call `useDashboardState` function? Also, read [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you are violating one of the rules.

Comment: `useDashboardState()` - this should be inside a react component; you cannot call a hook _outside_ of a react component.

Comment: if I remove `async` from the `withSubscription` , it works fine. so the problem is adding `async` in there.  why ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any other error or a warning in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not tested your code but i think problem here const `DashboardContext = React.createContext()`
try to create this hook inside of function component

Comment: `React.createContext()` is not a hook and it also doesn't creates a hook.